# Automated task

Tags: c#, windows, automation

I have a C# program that I want to run automatically every night without me having to do this,

I believe there is a way of doing this by setting an automated task however im not sure how to do this?

P.S. not sure if this helps but it has a .exe file in its library.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about registering this as a scheduled task?

Go to Control Panel -> Scheduled tasks.

Here you can easily add your exe as a task and choose when and how often to run your task.

In Windows 7 this is changed somewhat, but you can find it in

Control Panel -> System and Security -> Administrative Tools -> Task Scheduler

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at Windows Scheduled Tasks, not sure if it's available only on Windows Server or also XP, Vista, 7...

Comment: It is available on XP through Win7

Answer (score 1):

You can schedule tasks to run at whatever interval you like. I don't know what version of Windows you are using but here's [how to it in Windows XP](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308569)

Answer (score 0):

You can use "Scheduled Tasks" on windows.
You could also write your application as a "Windows Service". By this, it would run all the time on a machine, without someone creating a scheduled task.

Answer (score 0):

Windows scheduled tasks is the right way.

Look [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308569) for more information.

And [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Schedule-a-task) for how to do it in Windows 7