# Bulk insert CSV file into SQL Table with specific format

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, t-sql, backend

I am trying to do bulk insert throught a migration in C#, so far looks like this

```
    public override void Up()
    {
        Sql("BULK INSERT Test FROM 'C:\\test.csv' 
             WITH (
                   FORMATFILE = 'C:\\format.xml',
                   FIRSTROW = 2);"
             );
    }
```

test.csv

```
Id  Name    Birthday    Status
1   John    23-11-1984 00:00    OK
2   Peter   17-05-1986 00:00    N/A
3   James   18-03-1987 00:00    OK
```

format.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>  
<BCPFORMAT   
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/bulkload/format"   
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <RECORD>  
    <FIELD ID="1" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="\t"   MAX_LENGTH="12"/>
    <FIELD ID="2" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="\t"   MAX_LENGTH="20" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
    <FIELD ID="3" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="\t"   MAX_LENGTH="30"/>
    <FIELD ID="4" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="\r\n" MAX_LENGTH="30" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
  </RECORD>  
  <ROW>  
    <COLUMN SOURCE="1" NAME="Id" xsi:type="SQLINT"/>
    <COLUMN SOURCE="2" NAME="Name" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
    <COLUMN SOURCE="3" NAME="Birthday" xsi:type="SQLDATETIM8"/>
    <COLUMN SOURCE="4" NAME="Status" xsi:type="SQLBIT"/>
  </ROW>
</BCPFORMAT>
```

Test Table definition

```
Id (PK, not null)
Name (nvarchar(max), null)
Birthday (datetime, null)
Status (bit, null)
```

After updatig database I encountered first error (date format for Birthday in CSV is DD-MM-YYYY HH:MM):

> Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character
>   for the specified codepage) for row 3, column 3 (Birthday).

But if I change date format to YYYY-MM-DD HH:SS in the CSV file, it works.

Second issue is that for field 'Active' in CSV, I need to take the strings "OK" or "N/A" and in some way convert it and insert it in the table as Bit.

So at this point, my question is:

- Is there any way to convert this data before insert it into the table?

Comment: See msdn.  Use Mapping Class.  You may need to override the class to add custom methods.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopycolumnmapping.destinationordinal(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Take a look at DTS.  I would just parse directly in C#, fix the data, and load.

Comment: maybe this might work too? https://stackoverflow.com/a/45217654/6668185

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Automated task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4885640/automated-task)